# ImportError: No module named test_data, but test_data.py in same directory as test.py under PyCharm using virtualenv

Tags: python, import, virtualenv, pycharm, unittest2

In test.py, I am trying to import test_data:

```
import unittest2
import re

from test_data import receipt1_example
```

test_data.py is in the same directory as test.py. I get the following error:

> /Users/ahammond/.virtualenvs/ric2.6/bin/python2.6
>   /Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py
>   /Users/ahammond/src/hackfest_spring_2012/parse_me/test.py::test true
>   Testing started at 11:30 AM ... Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line
>   121, in 
>       module = loadSource(a[0])   File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 44, in
>   loadSource
>       module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)   File "/Users/ahammond/src/hackfest_spring_2012/parse_me/test.py", line 4,
>   in 
>       from test_data import receipt1_example ImportError: No module named test_data
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

As you can see, I am running this under pycharm using a virtualenv. Here's a screenshot of the configuration:

[image: PyCharm debug configuration]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The work around i use is:

```
import sys
import os
try:
    import test_data
except ImportError:
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    try:
        import test_data
    finally:
        sys.path.remove(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

A friend told me that one can also add the directory entries to some include directories.

Comment: Ugly, but works. Thanks! Er, obviously using

from test_data import receipt1_example

Answer (score 3):

Please try [PyCharm 2.5.1 RC](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/PYH/JetBrains+PyCharm+Preview), there was a bug with `sys.path` building (it contained incorrect, duplicated project source directory).

If it's not the case, you can mark additional directories as **Source** in `Preferences` | `Project Structure` or add them to the **Paths** in the `Python Interpreters`.

Comment: I updated to pycharm-117.296.dmg and still have the same error. P.S. You guys are awesome.

Comment: it hangs at " instantiating tests for me :( "

Comment: I actually do have the same problem with PyCharm 2.7

Comment: Me too :/ Still awesome IDE though.